# Finding which user has done a consecutive transaction in less than 10 minutes

Tags: mysql

I want to find which user has done a consecutive transaction in less than 10 minutes. I am having trouble how to deal with the time data type. I have the attached a picture of the dataset.

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYfBH.png)

```
SELECT user_id,
FROM set_1
WHERE TIMEDIFF (create_time-create_time) < 10 MIN
```

Comment: NO NEED TO YELL IN YOUR TITLES. :-)

Comment: The **function** TIMEDIFF takes two arguments. You have a minus sign where a comma should be: ```TIMEDIFF (create_time-create_time)``` should be ```TIMEDIFF (create_time,create_time)```. Also, to compare dates in different rows, you'll need to join the table to itself using two alias, then compare each row to the different rows, matching on user_id.

Answer (score 0):

The following explains what I said in the comment above. You join the table to itself, matching on user_id, and eliminating
matching a row to itself, then looking for rows that are within ten minutes of each other.

```
SELECT 
    `user_id`,
    a.`order_id` as `1st_order_id`,
    b.`order_id` as `2nd_order_id`
FROM `set_1` a
JOIN `set_1` b
ON a.`user_id` = b.`user_id` AND
    a.`order_id` != b.`order_id` AND
    TIMEDIFF(a.`order_id`,b.`order_id`) < INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

**NOTE:** *Not tested, may contain typos*.

Comment: Yes, but I only want the result to be just user_id

Comment: I'm curious... how did you manage to answer this? I closed it as a duplicate (and it is an **exact** duplicate) 19 minutes earlier...

Comment: No idea unless I was already editing it when you closed it.